# Patching Async Object in Python 3.8

Tags: python, async-await, pytest, python-asyncio, python-3.8

I have a newbie question about mock patching async object with Python 3.8. All I am trying is to mock post() so that I can test the error handling logic, but so far I have had no luck. Could you please tell me what I did wrong? Thanks a lot.

**main.py**

```
import httpx


test_data = {"id": "123"}

class DebugClass:
    def post(self):
        try:
            async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
                res = await client.post(url='http://localhost:8080', data=test_data)
            return "OK"
        except Exception as e:
            return "NOK"
```

**test_main.py**

```
from unittest import mock
from unittest.mock import patch, AsyncMock


from main import DebugClass

class TestClass:
    @mock.patch('httpx.AsyncClient.post', new_callable=AsyncMock)
    def test_post(self, mock_client_post):
        mock_client_post = AsyncMock(side_effect=TimeoutError)
        debug_class = DebugClass()
        res = debug_class.post()
        assert res == "NOK"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing `asyncio` code by means of `pytest` I would suggest you to use libs [pytest-asyncio](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio) and [asynctest](https://asynctest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

To install: `pip install pytest-asyncio asynctest`.

Below is an example based on your code:

```
import httpx
import asynctest
import pytest


class DebugClass:
    async def post(self):
        try:
            async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
                res = await client.post(url='http://localhost:8080', data=test_data)
            return "OK"
        except Exception as e:
            return "NOK"


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_debug_class_post():
    with asynctest.patch('httpx.AsyncClient.post') as post_mock:
        post_mock.side_effect = TimeoutError
        debug_class = DebugClass()
        res = await debug_class.post()
        assert res == "NOK"
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help Alex! It works :)! I just have one more question. When I run your code, pytest returned this warning:

DeprecationWarning: "@coroutine" decorator is deprecated since Python 3.8, use "async def" instead
    def wait(self, skip=0):

Just out of curiosity, is there any alternative syntax to pytest.mark.asyncio? Thx :)

Comment: As of today, unfortunately, the `asyntest` has not yet been updated to support the new syntax, so I can only advise you to [disable](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html#deprecationwarning-and-pendingdeprecationwarning) deprecation warning

Comment: Noted. Thx a lot Alex.